# Haskell: Creating Type Classes for Zippers

Tags: haskell, design-patterns, typeclass, zipper

So I've been reading a bit about the Zipper pattern in Haskell (and other functional languages, I suppose) to traverse and modify a data structure, and I thought that this would be a good chance for me to hone my skills at creating type classes in Haskell, since
the class could present a common traversal interface for me to write code to, independent of the data structure traversed.

I thought I'd probably need two classes - one for the root data structure, and one for the special data structure created
to traverse the first:

```
module Zipper where

class Zipper z where
  go'up :: z -> Maybe z
  go'down :: z -> Maybe z
  go'left :: z -> Maybe z
  go'right :: z -> Maybe z

class Zippable t where
  zipper :: (Zipper z) => t -> z
  get :: (Zipper z) => z -> t
  put :: (Zipper z) => z -> t -> z
```

But when I tried these with some simple datastructures like a list:

```
-- store a path through a list, with preceding elements stored in reverse
data ListZipper a = ListZipper { preceding :: [a], following :: [a] }

instance Zipper (ListZipper a) where
  go'up ListZipper { preceding = [] } = Nothing
  go'up ListZipper { preceding = a:ps, following = fs } = 
      Just $ ListZipper { preceding = ps, following = a:fs }
  go'down ListZipper { following = [] } = Nothing
  go'down ListZipper { preceding = ps, following = a:fs } = 
      Just $ ListZipper { preceding = a:ps, following = fs }
  go'left _ = Nothing
  go'right _ = Nothing

instance Zippable ([a]) where
  zipper as = ListZipper { preceding = [], following = as }
  get = following
  put z as = z { following = as }
```

Or a binary tree:

```
-- binary tree that only stores values at the leaves
data Tree a = Node { left'child :: Tree a, right'child :: Tree a } | Leaf a
-- store a path down a Tree, with branches not taken stored in reverse
data TreeZipper a = TreeZipper { branches :: [Either (Tree a) (Tree a)], subtree :: Tree a }

instance Zipper (TreeZipper a) where
  go'up TreeZipper { branches = [] } = Nothing
  go'up TreeZipper { branches = (Left l):bs, subtree = r } =  
      Just $ TreeZipper { branches = bs, subtree = Node { left'child = l, right'child = r } }
  go'up TreeZipper { branches = (Right r):bs, subtree = l } =  
      Just $ TreeZipper { branches = bs, subtree = Node { left'child = l, right'child = r } }
  go'down TreeZipper { subtree = Leaf a } = Nothing
  go'down TreeZipper { branches = bs, subtree = Node { left'child = l, right'child = r } } =
      Just $ TreeZipper { branches = (Right r):bs, subtree = l }
  go'left TreeZipper { branches = [] } = Nothing
  go'left TreeZipper { branches = (Right r):bs } = Nothing
  go'left TreeZipper { branches = (Left l):bs, subtree = r } =
      Just $ TreeZipper { branches = (Right r):bs, subtree = l }
  go'right TreeZipper { branches = [] } = Nothing
  go'right TreeZipper { branches = (Left l):bs } = Nothing
  go'right TreeZipper { branches = (Right r):bs, subtree = l } =
      Just $ TreeZipper { branches = (Left l):bs, subtree = r }

instance Zippable (Tree a) where
  zipper t = TreeZipper { branches = [], subtree = t }
  get TreeZipper { subtree = s } = s
  put z s = z { subtree = s }
```

I couldn't get it to compile, I'd just get a lot of errors like this for each of my `Zippable` instance definitions:

```
Zipper.hs:28:14:
    Couldn't match expected type `z'
           against inferred type `ListZipper a'
      `z' is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for `zipper' at Zipper.hs:10:20
    In the expression: ListZipper {preceding = [], following = as}
    In the definition of `zipper':
        zipper as = ListZipper {preceding = [], following = as}
    In the definition for method `zipper'
```

So I'm not sure where to go from here.  I suspect that my issue is that I'm trying to bind these two instances 
together, when the `(Zipper z) =>` declaration just wants `z` to be any `Zipper`.

Comment: How about adding a Monad instance using the zipper as a state variable.  Then to swap two items you say "x <- get; goDown; y <- get; put x; goUp; put y"

Comment: That's what I did tonight actually :)  http://gist.github.com/115203

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(Aside: your `go'up` naming scheme is... inventive.  Haskell style is usually camelCase.)

You're on the right track.  What you've written is equivalent to the below.

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
instance Zippable [a] where
    zipper = ... :: forall z. (Zipper z) => [a] -> z
    get = ... :: forall z. (Zipper z) => z -> [a]
    set = ... :: forall z. (Zipper z) => z -> [a] -> z
```

(For all types `z`, given `Zipper z`, there exists a `zipper :: [a] -> z`.)

You're tring to define `zipper = ... :: [a] -> ListZipper a`, which is clearly too restrictive.

Your code will typecheck with the following minimal changes:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
class (Zipper z) => Zippable z t where
    zipper :: t -> z
    get :: z -> t
    set :: z -> t -> z
instance Zippable (ListZipper a) [a] where
    ...
instance Zippable (TreeZipper a) (Tree a) where
    ...
```

See [multi-parameter type classes](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Multi-parameter_type_class).  It's a post-Haskell'98 extension, but Haskell implementations widely support it.

Comment: +1/accepted - thank you very much!  I'm slowly learning Haskell, and really haven't learned the naming conventions yet, but I'll get there.

Comment: OT: when should I use the apostrophe in names?

Comment: I have only seen it used as "prime". Like in `let x' = x + 1`. It should be used to name values that are slight modifications of old values.

Comment: Following http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_(symbol) usage in mathematics, the apostrophe is only used at the end of names, and is used to name a related value.

Comment: It's not always used to name modified old values, although that is common.  In the standard library, foldl' is a stricter variant of foldl.

Comment: Probably it's a good idea to add a functional dependency t->z to Zippable. Otherwise you will run into type ambiguities when you try to use these classes... (see also http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Functional_dependencies)

Comment: @sth: What I provided was just a minimal change to get the existing code to typecheck, but yes, `class (Zipper z) => Zippable z t | t -> z` would make the code more usable.  I was hoping that OP would follow the link to multi-parameter type classes and read "Without functional dependencies or associated types, these multi-parameter type classes may cause too much ambiguity to pass the type-checker", but perhaps it would have been better to be more explicit.

Comment: Much thanks sth, that helped me get past the wall I was banging my head against.

Answer (score 8):

You can also use type synonym families instead of multi-parameter type classes and functional dependencies. In cases like these they offer a cleaner and easier-to-understand solution. In that case the class and instance would become:

```
class Zippable t where
  type ZipperType t :: *
  enter :: t -> ZipperType t
  focus :: ZipperType t -> t

instance Zippable [a] where
  type ZipperType [a] = ListZipper a
  enter = ...
  focus = ...
```

[Fun with type functions](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/papers/assoc-types/typefun.pdf) is an excellent introduction to type synonym families for people already familiar with Haskell. I also wrote [an article](http://martijn.van.steenbergen.nl/journal/2009/01/11/type-synonym-families/) on how type synonym families can often be used instead of functional dependencies a while ago.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Type families were introduced around GHC 6.10.1 or so?  I've yet to actually make use of them, but they seem handy.